# Loudness on Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

The scenario is that I start the recording at in my iphone app maybe by using AVAudioRecoder and when i have some input sound above certain threshold then i will do some thing. Is it possible to process the input audio while recoding??

Is there any way to know the input loudness in iPhone. Like what is the level of the loudness in numbers or if there is any other measure for that.

Comment: what do you mean when you say input? do you want to set the volume level or just get its value?

Comment: By input i mean that there is a continuous input of the surrounding voices and when there is the voice above the certain threshold then i will come to know.

Comment: Please update your question with more explanation of the scenario you are trying to implement...eg ur taking sound as input and trying to calculate how loud it is etc.

Comment: Its like that, i have started the recording at some time in iphone maybe by using AVAudioRecoder and when i have some input sound above certain threshold then i will do some thing.Do you think that whether is it possible to process the input audio while recoding and if you have some way to do that please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at AVFoundation, AVAudioRecorder and enable the property `meteringEnabled` to get threshold change callbacks.